# codeigniter extending MY_Controller increase page loading time

Tags: codeigniter, model, controller

I extend Codeigniter CI_controller. is there any impact on page loading time?.
along with this i create a model with name **global_model**, inside this model i create dynamic method to **ADD, UPDATE, DELETE, FETCH** data through passing parameter in the method.is this model work smooth with heavy data or will crash?. model look like something this:-

```
 public function add($table, $data) {
    return $this->db
                    ->insert($table, $data);
}

public function delete($table, $where) {
    return $this->db
                    ->delete($table, $where);
}

public function update($table, $where, $data) {
    return $this->db
                    ->where($where)
                    ->update($table, $data);
}
```

Comment: It will work fine, but do not write ```return```, instead get affected record status and return it. I don't think ```MY_Controller``` will affect the page loading time. Show your ```My_Controller```

Comment: why shouldn't return in model method ?

Comment: They all are returning ```true``` all the time. Specially ```update``` of codeigniter.